# How to use active query method of another model class via relation in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have models like below

```
/**
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $title
 */
class Book extends ActiveRecord {
    public static function find() {
        return new BookQuery(self::class);
    }
}

class BookQuery extends ActiveQuery {
    public function andWhereTitleLike($string) {
        return $this->andWhere(['like', 'title', $string]);
    }
}

/**
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $userId
 * @property integer $bookId
 * @property integer $addedTime
 */
class FavoriteBook extends ActiveRecord {
     public function getBook() {
        return $this->hasOne(Book::class, ['id' => 'bookId']);
     }
}
```

Querying favorite books of the current logged user is like below

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => FavoriteBook::find()
                   ->andWhere(['userId' => Yii::$app->user->id])
]);
```

But how do I query favorite book of the user that contains a certain title by reusing the method in the `BookQuery` above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got the answer

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => FavoriteBook::find()
               ->joinWith([
                   'book' => function(BookQuery $query) use ($title) {
                      return $query->andWhereTitleLike($title);
                   }
               ])
               ->andWhere(['userId' => Yii::$app->user->id])
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "joinWith" like following way

```
FavoriteBook::find()
->joinWith(Book)    
->andWhere(['userId' => Yii::$app->user->id])
```

To make sure its working you can get all Array, print record and make confirm like following.

```
$fav_book = FavoriteBook::find()
->joinWith(Book)    
->andWhere(['userId' => Yii::$app->user->id])
->asArray()->all();

var_dump($fav_book);
```